# How to sort and get unique values from an array in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

Im new to bash scripting... Im trying to sort and store unique values from an array into another array.
eg:

```
list=('a','b','b','b','c','c');
```

I need,

```
unique_sorted_list=('b','c','a')
```

I tried a couple of things, didnt help me ..

```
sorted_ids=($(for v in "${ids[@]}"; do echo "$v";done| sort| uniq| xargs))
```

or

```
sorted_ids=$(echo "${ids[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Can you guys please help me in this ....

Comment: Take the `| xargs` out of your first try.

Comment: hi kevin , tried that .. but I see no difference..

Comment: @kevin . I understood now ...everythings fine...it sorts as (a b c) but I need (b c a) since it has b is three times c 2times and a once.. That is the question i intended to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ list=(a b b b c c)
$ unique_sorted_list=($(printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | sort -u))
$ echo "${unique_sorted_list[@]}"
a b c
```

#### Update based on comments:

```
$ uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rnk1 | awk '{ print $2 }'))
```

Comment: Hi Jaypal , your case works, But :-(  in my case it is ('a','a','a','b','b','b') not (a a a b b b b b) ....Because of the quotes it takes each value to be unique and prints the same array ...I guess

Comment: actually my array contains user names of files...This is how I get it

Comment: for file in $fList; do
        dList+="$(ls -lt $file | awk '{ print $3 }')"
done     -------  from dList I need to get sorted , unique array

Comment: @Karthik In bash the array elements are separated by a space.

Comment: @jayapal..thanks I understand this.. but when I do the command "for file in $flist.."  given in my previous comment   and when I do echo $dList it prints the names without any space ...thats the problem..

Comment: why it does not add a space to my array when I append items?

Comment: Hi Jayapal... I understood now ...everythings fine...In your solution it sorts as a b c    but I need b c a since it has b is three times c 2times and a once.. That is my question i wanted to ask...

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work if array elements contain spaces.

Try this instead:

```sh
readarray -t unique_sorted_list < <( printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | sort -u )
```

In Bash, `readarray` is an alias to the built-in `mapfile` command. See `help mapfile` for details.

The `-t` option is to remove the trailing newline (used in `printf`) from each line read.